# TYPO3 HTTPS://www. redirects to Page Not Found

Tags: https, typo3

Hope that someone can help me solve this strange https:// behaviour in TYPO3 8.7.2 (and 7.6)
All https:// referrers are working fine. The only one giving a problem is the https://www.hocom-advies.nl which produces an url like this: 
https://www.hocom-advies.nl/hocom-advies.nl which results in a TYPO3 error: Page not found! ??

I have all rewriting in my Vhost. Only some basic TYPO3 rewrite stuff in the .htaccess file. And some basic TS lines in the config.
The same https request on an other TYPO3 8.7.2 system is working ok! Both settings in the VHost and TSconfig are equal.
So where to look for here? Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

your domain duplication can have multiple reasons:

- have you configured `config.absRefPrefix = /` (or have you inserted your domain?)
- don't use baseURL!
- are your rewrites clean? (no missing protocols?)
- do you generate links without protocol?